# NIPS appliance 100 MB limit pcap find vlan id tag

Tags: vlan, tcpdump

**Background**
I have a Network IPS Appliance at work. The configuration is not well documented and I want to work out what traffic has been configured to flow through which interfaces. The network is segmented i.e. 802.1q vlan

The IPS allows capture of 100 MB of traffic then stops. The NIPS supports most tcpdump commands but not all.

**Idea**
Capture traffic on each interface and track which traffic is flowing through it by vlan id.
Since I have a limit of 100 MB I only want to capture the ethernet header including the vlan tag. I do NOT want the payload because it fills up the 100MB limit much too fast.

**What I need**
A tcpdump expression that capture the first 16Bytes only i.e. destination mac, source mac and 802.1q header.

I will then use wireshark or similar to read the 100MB capture and work out what traffic flows through the link.

**Weaknesses**
I appreciate that I am using the wrong tool (tcpdump) for this job (identify traffic). It would be better to use netflow or zeek to identify traffic flows but I have nothing else available to me. That being said I am open to ideas.

I will post back on progress - if it works or not. Thanks for reading. J

Comment: Is there any chance you are able to get the official vendor documentation? Or can you access a console and then check the logs?you could also check for the existence of common open source ids software like suricata or snort

Comment: Thanks for posting. I used tcpdump -s 64 to cpature the first 64 bytes which includes the vlan tag id
I hope this helps others.